# How to correctly sign the transfer of tokens through the smatcontract?

Tags: transactions, ethereum, smartcontracts, web3js, hardhat

I have [smartcontract](https://hardhat.org/tutorial/writing-and-compiling-contracts.html) with method transfer:

```
function transfer(address to, uint256 amount) external {
    require(balances[msg.sender] >= amount, "Not enough tokens");
    balances[msg.sender] -= amount;
    balances[to] += amount;
}
```

After deploy via [HardHat](https://hardhat.org/tutorial/deploying-to-a-live-network.html) with account alchemy: "https://eth-ropsten.alchemyapi.io/v2/iwxxx"

I got:
Deploying contracts with the account: 0x5Cххх
Account balance: 299502973995526766
Token address: 0xC1ххх

And run this code:

```
const acc_addr = "0x5Cxxx";
const address = "0xC1xxx"           
const receiverAddress  = "0x39xxx"  


var Web3 = require('web3')
var provider = "https://eth-ropsten.alchemyapi.io/v2/iwxxx";
var web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider(provider));

const token = new web3.eth.Contract(abi, address);
token.setProvider(web3.currentProvider)

token.methods.balanceOf(acc_addr).call((err, res) => {  
    log("balanse => ", res); 
});


token.methods.transfer(receiverAddress, "1").send({ "from": acc_addr }, (err, res) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      return
    }
    console.log("Hash transaction: " + res);
});
```

So I got error:

> Error: Returned error: Unsupported method: eth_sendTransaction.
> Alchemy does not hold users' private keys. See available methods at
> https://docs.alchemy.com/alchemy/documentation/apis

> at Object.ErrorResponse (D:\node_modules\web3-core-helpers\lib\errors.js:28:19)

I understand that I somehow have to sign this transaction. But the question is, I don’t understand how?

Normal transactions of transferring ETH from an address to an address are very simple and obvious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass the private key of the transaction sender (`acc_addr` in your case) to your local web3 instance using the [wallet.add()](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.5.2/web3-eth-accounts.html#wallet-add) method.

```
web3.eth.accounts.wallet.add('0x<private_key>');
```

*Note: Web3 does not share the private key with the node provider - uses it only to sign the transaction locally.*

Comment: When I deployed the token I didn't get the privet Key: https://hardhat.org/tutorial/deploying-to-a-live-network.html only those keys that I mentioned earlier.